# Luasql(Sqlite3) aceitando apenas um "valor"

Tags: lua, sqlite3

Estou tentando criar uma tabela simples, apenas com nomes, mas quando eu insiro um valor, não dá mais de inserir outros.
Como estou fazendo:

```
require 'luasql.sqlite3'

local env = luasql.sqlite3()
local con = env:connect('database.s3db')

con:execute([[
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
name varchar(50)
)
]])

con:execute([[
INSERT INTO users VALUES('Alguem');
INSERT INTO users VALUES('Outro');
INSERT INTO users VALUES('Mais Outro');
]])
cur = assert(con:execute([[
SELECT * FROM users
]]))
local result = {}
cur:fetch(result, 'a')

for i,v in pairs(result) do
    print(i,v)
end
cur:close()

con:close()
env:close()
os.execute('pause')
```

No caso, imprime só:

```
name Alguem
```

Quando deveria imprimir:

```
name Alguem
name Outro
name Mais Outro
```

Comment: Nunca usei LuaSQL mas parece estar tudo certo exceto pelo `assert`, é para ele estar ali mesmo?

Comment: Sim, e mesmo retirando-o, continua a não funcionar como desejado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui arrumar, haviam dois erros.
O primeiro:

```
con:execute([[
INSERT INTO users VALUES('Alguem');
INSERT INTO users VALUES('Outro');
INSERT INTO users VALUES('Mais Outro');
]])
```

Desse modo, ele executa apenas a 1 linha, o jeito correto é:

```
con:execute("INTSERT INTO users VALUES('Alguem')")
con:execute("INTSERT INTO users VALUES('Outro')")
con:execute("INTSERT INTO users VALUES('Mais Outro')")
```

Ou seja, cada um é chamado em "linhas"/"funções" diferentes.

O segundo erro:

```
local result = {}
cur:fetch(result, 'a')

for i,v in pairs(result) do
    print(i,v)
end
```

Este modo está errado, como diz na documentação sobre a funçao fetch, "Retrieves the next row of results.", logo ele fica sempre no primeiro resultado.

O modo certo é:

```
local row = cur:fetch({}, 'a')
while row do
    print('Name: '..row.name)
    row = cur:fetch(row, 'a')
end
```

Completo, ficou assim:

```
require 'luasql.sqlite3'

local env = luasql.sqlite3()
local con = env:connect('database.s3db')

con:execute([[
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
name varchar(50)
)
]])

con:execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES('Alguem');")
con:execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES('Outro');")
con:execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES('Mais Outro');")

cur = assert(con:execute([[
SELECT * FROM users
]]))

local row = cur:fetch({}, 'a')
while row do
    print('Name: '..row.name)
    row = cur:fetch(row, 'a')
end

cur:close()

con:close()
env:close()
os.execute('pause')
```